# Allow port 1352 via UFW and Squid

Tags: squid, ufw

Our server runs UFW and Squid (along with SquidGuard). All the systems in our LAN connect to the Internet via this server. UFW seems to allow port 1352. Squid also seems to allow connections on port 1352 as it is marked as a SafePort in squid.conf. But somehow Lotus Notes is unable to connect to the email servers. I might be missing something very simple. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to telnet to port 1352 from outside the network?  Does it give you a "Connect Failed" error or does it just sit there.  If you get the "Connect Failed" then there is a firewall rule still blocking your connection.

Comment: @Optichip, from outside the network and from the server itself, telnet <server ip> <1352> succeeds. But from any of the systems in the LAN, telnet fails.

Comment: so internally you can't get to your server?  Sounds like there's a firewall rule in place internally that was missed.  Are the e-mail server and LAN on the same network segment?  Are you using load balancers, F5s etc?

Comment: No, internally we can get to the server. I can telnet to the applications hosted on the server. I can't telnet to the external sites like www.google.com or anything else. But I can access www.google.com in the browser. I am not sure what is blocking telnet particularly. Noob here :(  

The email server is on the Internet. I can access the web version of the email from the browser. I cannot access it from Lotus Notes. No load balancers. I am not sure what F5s are.